# $\int_Xfgd\mu=0\;\forall g$ in a dense subset of $L^q\Rightarrow f=0$ a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, almost-everywhere

Let $(X,\mathscr{E},\mu)$ be a measure space, $p\in(1,\infty)$, $q=\frac{p}{p-1}$ and $S\subset L^q$ be a dense subset.
Then

$$f\in L^p \text{ and } \int_Xfgd\mu=0  \text{     } \forall g\in S => f=0 \text{ }\mu\text{-almost-everywhere}$$

I'm not sure whether my proof is correct and I haven't found anything on the internet yet that solves this question. So I would appreciate really much if anyone could give me some feedback for my proof:

Assume $f\neq0$ a.e. then $\exists E\subset X$ such that $ \mu(E)\neq0$ and $f\neq0$ on $E$.

Now here's the part that might be wrong: I can choose $E$ such that $\mu(E)<\infty$.

Then $\unicode{x1D7D9}_E\in L^q$ and since S is dense, we can approximate $\unicode{x1D7D9}_E$ by a growing sequence $g_n
\in S$.
Then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_Xfgd\mu=\int_Xf\unicode{x1D7D9}_Ed\mu\neq0$.

Comment: @Kekks Does this measure space satisfy any hypothesis like sigma finiteness? On the other hand, you want to assume $f \neq 0$ _on a set of positive measure_ rather than a.e. But then you can assume $f > \delta$ on a set $\mathrm{E}$ and sice $f$ is of $p$th integrable power, $\mathrm{E}$ is of finite measure.

Comment: There's no further info than what I have written here, so no sigma finiteness. As you already mentioned For some ϵ>0 the set {x : f(x) < ϵ} or {x : f(x) > ϵ} has finite, nonzero measure (otherwhise f∉Lp and f=0 a.e.) and using this should make my proof valid, shouldnt it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only potential problem with choosing $E$ so $0 < \mu(E) < \infty$ is that there are positive measures $\mu$ with sets $E$ such that $\mu(E) = \infty$ and no measurable subset of $E$ has nonzero finite measure.  But that can't happen here, because $f \in L^p$  and $f \ne 0$ on $E$.  Consider sets of the form $\{x: f(x) > \epsilon\}$ (or $< - \epsilon$).

Comment: So I can use {x: f(x)>$\epsilon$} or  {x: f(x)<$\epsilon$} with some (if needed really small $\epsilon > 0$ because it's measure is less than infinity (otherwhise $f \notin L^p). And I also do not encounter the problem BigbearZzz mentioned in his answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one problem: Having $f\ne 0$ on $E$ doesn't imply that
$$
\int_E f\, d\mu \ne 0.
$$
For instance, the positive and negative part of $f$ could cancel each other on $E$.

I suggest that you use the fact that for $X=L^p$ you have $X^*\simeq L^q$.

Comment: I hoped that I could define an $Ê \subset E$ so that f is only positive or negative on this new set.

Comment: I agree that it'd be a good idea :)

Comment: But would you mind explaining what the $*$ and $\simeq$ means? I think $\simeq$ means isomorphic, but what does the star mean?

Comment: I was referring to the fact that $L^q$ "is" (isomorphic to) the dual space of $L^p$.

Comment: Oh, I tried to use this first, but I wasn't able to come up with any usefull information from this fact. So with the comment of Robert Israel I have: For some $\epsilon > 0$ the set {x : f(x) < $\epsilon $} or {x : f(x) > $\epsilon $} has finite, nonzero measure (otherwhise $f \notin L^p$ and f=0 a.e.) Using this set for the characteristic function would make my proof right?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f \neq 0$, then Hahn Banach shows that there is some $\gamma \in (L^p)^*$
such that $\gamma(f) = 1$. Since $(L^p)^* \cong L^q$, we have some $g \in L^q$ such that
$\int f g d \mu= 1$.

Since $S$ is dense, we have some $g^*$ such that $\int f g^* d \mu > {1 \over 2}$.